# Is there a `clearmake` option to change make distant directory?

Tags: makefile, clearcase

There is option in makefile as `make -C /pathname` (so it build the targeted path).

Is there anything similar in `clearmake`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using `clearmake -C gnu`.
See "[makefile_gnu](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/makefile_gnu.htm)".

> #### Supported GNU make command options
>
> `clearmake –C gnu` supports most of the single-character and long-form spellings of GNU make command options, as follows:
>
> - `-directory=dir`
>   Change to the specified directory before reading the makefiles.

(And that is fairly similar to the [gnu `make` option `-C`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary):

> - ‘`-C dir`’
>   ‘`--directory=dir`’
>   Change to directory `dir` before reading the makefiles.
>   If multiple ‘`-C`’ options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: ‘`-C / -C etc`’ is equivalent to ‘`-C /etc`’.
>   This is typically used with recursive invocations of `make` (see [Recursive Use of `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion)).

)

Comment: so to make at path suppose /usr/bin/anuj ...i need to give following command:clearmake -C gnu -d /usr/bin/anuj

Comment: @user1416780 it seems to be what the documentation requires (except you might need an '`=`': `clearmake -C gnu -directory=/usr/bin/anuj`), but I don't have direct experience with it. It also supposes you are doing it on a platform/OS which already support native *gnu* make.